# Leer archivos de memoria JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Tengo una aplicación que escribe a memoria un resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
 using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(sMemfile, 1028))
 {
    using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
    {
         BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
         writer.Write(resultado);
     }
 }
```

Sé que para leer el resultado desde otra aplicación se utiliza el siguiente proceso:

```
using (MemoryMappedFile mmfile = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(sMemfile))
{
     using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmfile.CreateViewStream())
     {
           BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
           resultado = reader.ReadString();
     }
}
```

Pero quisiera hacer este último desde un sitio web con JQuery, hay alguna forma o método similar a MemoryMappedFile que me permita leer lo que mi aplicación me envió? Gracias!